# How to see the actual server side error message in the browser?

Tags: asp-classic, internal-server-error

I'm having a trouble reproducing an issue a user is having in IE, but something that always bugged me is how can I see the error message from classic ASP page in IE for example on a dev server.

In IE all I see is for example:

> This page contains programming error

And that's it.

**Note: since this is server side, it applies to all browsers.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember this one!

You need to go into ie settings > advanced > uncheck "show friendly http errors"

[image]

Comment: It should. If not your IIS settings are not allowing the error to be sent to the client.

Comment: @StevieB - Yes. Ditto what Breadtruck said. I always remember having to do that on a new machine with IE - because it tries to hide the actual details of the error behind a user-friendly facade. If you do that and you aren't getting error details - make sure IIS is configured to send them to the client.